# Aggregate total and distinct count

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document to stored products, one receipt can have many products inside.

```
{"_id" : "59871e65fffe165420e0b324"
"receiptid" : "4BA/ZFY7AQ4HvfjUMTRTLg=="
"area_type" : 1
"report_type" : 3
"id_station" : 2317
"date" : "2017-08-05 00:00:00.000"
"time" : "1501979220"
"amount" : 10113958
"item" : 32
},
{"_id" : "59871e65fffe165420e0b324"
"receiptid" : "4BA/ZFY7AQ4HvfjUMTRTLg=="
"area_type" : 1
"report_type" : 3
"id_station" : 2317
"date" : "2017-08-05 00:00:00.000"
"time" : "1501979320"
"amount" : 4000000
"item" : 12
}
```

I want to count total amount and total receipt in one query:

```
$store = array(2317);
$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$match' => [ 'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ], 'date' => ['$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-01")*1000), '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-01")*1000)]  ] ],              

    ['$group' => ['_id' => ["id_station" => '$id_station'], 
                 "amountclient"=> ['$sum' => '$amount']
                ]
    ],
    ['$group' => ['_id' => ["id_station" => '$id_station', "receiptid" => '$receiptid'], 
                 "receipt"=> ['$sum' => 1]
                ]
    ]
]);
```

But the query doesn't show anything, how can I correct it?
I want the result:
{"store" => xxxx, "amount" => xxxx, "number of receipt" => xxx}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want "distinct counts", which means you actually "compound" the grouping the other way around to what you are attempting:

```
$store = array(2317);
$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
    ['$match' => [ 
      'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ],
      'date' => [
        '$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-01")*1000),
        '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-01")*1000)
      ]
    ]],              
    ['$group' => [
      '_id' => [ 'id_station' => '$id_station', 'receiptid' => '$receiptid' ],
      'amount' => [ '$sum' => '$amount' ]
    ]],
    [ '$group' => [
      '_id' => '$_id.id_station',
      'amount' => [ '$sum' => '$amount' ],
      'numReceipt' => [ '$sum' => 1 ]
    ]]
]);
```

The first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) "includes" the `"receiptid"` field in the grouping `_id` so that the results returns are the "distinct" combination of the two keys. This allows the accumulation of the `"amount"` over that combination, and means that only the "distinct" values of `"receipt_id"` per each `"id_station"` are actually returned.

The "second" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) cuts down the key to just the "distinct" `"id_station"` value alone. Note the notation as `'$_id.id_station'` since the value was placed in a "compound key" of the `_id` in the previous [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. This is how "pipelines" work, by only having the available "input" that was the "output" of the previous stage.

For the `"amount"` you can pass the value into [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) again, and where there were "multiple combinations of `"id_station"` and `"receiptid"` then this is now reduced down to the total for just the `"id_station"` key. So you are "totaling the totals" from the previous stage output by the new reduced grouping key.

As for the "number of receipts", since the first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) made those values "distinct" within each `"id_station"`, then the number is simply the `[ '$sum' => 1 ]` result.

Basically on the included data in the question where both the keys are shared in the documents, it would return the "total amount" and the count of `1` for the "receipts" since there is only one "distinct" value.